# How can I get buttons inside a div inside a row to wrap? (flex and angular)

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

So I've got a kind of header, that contains a heading and a bunch of buttons. These buttons can be added to, so it's important to me that they wrap properly.

The catch is that these buttons are fed in via angular as an outside component, and as such they get put in a div (I'm assuming?)

In this codepen I have illustrated the result I want to reach (blue) vs. what I'm getting (red). It's hard to see on the snippet so here is a [link to a codepen](https://codepen.io/meek/pen/BmVdWa?editors=1100). To be clear, I want the buttons to wrap individually, one by one, rather than as a group.

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row red">
  <h1>Really long annoying header goes here</h1>
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row blue">
  <h1>Really long annoying header goes here</h1>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
</div>
```

By the way, here is the component selection-buttons.component.html:

```
<button class="selectionbtn selectbtn" *ngFor="let btn of input.items;let idx = index" (click)="onSelect(idx)" [ngClass]="{'first': idx === 0, 'last': idx === input?.items?.length -1, 'active': currIndex === idx }" value="idx">{{btn.label | translate}}</button>
```

I made sure to remove the div they were being generated inside, which made me think that when  gets called, they would just be generated inside the current div, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: One possible way is to remove `display: flex` and make all children _inline_  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaRaKE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With block like elements, as flex items are, browsers will start wrapping the outer one's first and the inner one's last.

Knowing that, one possible solutions it to make all children inline elements, which also mean the `display: flex` needs to be removed from the outer most parent.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaRaKE)

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-row {
  /*display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;*/
}

.flex-row * {
  display: inline;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row red">
  <h1>Really long annoying header goes here</h1>
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row blue">
  <h1>Really long annoying header goes here</h1>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the simplest and *best supported* solution.

Comment: I can't believe that for once the solution to the problem is to not use flex. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is **possible** with flexbox but only by using a poorly supported property on the inner div.

> `display: contents;`
>
> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.
>
> <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)</sup>

Support is essentially, Chrome (58+) & FF (37+)

Note: Up to Chrome 63 (*"In Chrome, the contents value is currently disabled by default, but can be enabled with the "Experimental Web Platform features" flag."*)

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.red div {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row red">
  <h1>Really long header goes here</h1>
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `display:flex` to `button` wrap `div` class like:

```
.red div{
  display:flex;
}
```

**Note** : Please check in full page.

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.red div{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row red">
  <h1>Really long annoying header goes here</h1>
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row blue">
  <h1>Really long annoying header goes here</h1>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however this doesn't seem to solve the problem. when you resize the browser, the buttons still wrap as a group instead of individually.